# Decryption logic using bit rotate

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to write a decrypt logic for the below encrypt logic.

```
import os
import string

keybytes = bytes(os.urandom(8))
bit = keybytes[0] % 7 + 1
kxor = []
key = ""

for i in range(1, 8):
    kxor.append(ord(string.ascii_letters[keybytes[i] % len(string.ascii_letters)]))
    key = key + chr(kxor[i-1])
print("Key is %s rotated by %d bits." % (key, bit))

def rotatel(x, bit):
    return ((x << bit) & 0xff) | (x >> (8 - bit))

plaintext = "ABCDE"
bit = 6
kxor = [65,115,113,107,98,75,85]
encryptedText = []
for i in range(0, len(plaintext)):
    encryptedText.append(rotatel(plaintext[i], bit) ^ kxor[i % len(kxor)])
print (bytes.encryptedText)
```

Now, the `bit` and `kxor` values, I have hardcoded them as I am able to get them back; meaning if these were the values I used for encryption therefore I am able to get `kxor` programmatically while writing the decryption logic.
Where I am struggling is the `rotatel` function.
I am trying to reverse that logic but I am not able to figure out how. So need some pointers to reverse the `rotatel` function.
Is that the right way or am i approaching this entirely in a wrong way?

Basically my question is how do i reverse  `return ((x << bit) & 0xff) | (x >> (8 - bit))`

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
bit = 6
x = "123456"
rotatel(x, bit) = "561234"
```

so what you need is:

```
y = "561234"
reverse_rotatel(y, bit) = "123456"
```

But you must remember that you `xor` *y* (561234) with `kxor` after you `rotatel`. So you must `xor` again with `kxor` to get *y* before you `reverse_rotatel`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I was looking to figure out the reverse logic for return ((x << bit) & 0xff) | (x >> (8 - bit)). I actually modified my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally figure it out. I wanted to write a reverse logic for rotatel-

```
def rotatel(x, bit):
    return ((x << bit) & 0xff) | (x >> (8 - bit))
```

This is how I did it -

```
def rotater(x, bit):
    return ((x >> bit)& 0xff) | (x << (8 - bit)) & 0xff
```